# Select2 plugin in angularjs puts the list out of controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 angularjs directive, which uses the select2 jquery plugin.  I am facing a problem with the list of the select2 is not shown properly.

Below is my view :

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="new-proj">

    <select
            ui-select2="{dropdownCssClass:dropdown-menu}"
            multiple
            ng-model="data.selectedCountries"
            data-placeholder="Choose or Search for countries"
            name="countries"
            style="width:200px;">
            <option ng-repeat="country in data.countriesList" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When the data is fetched from the controller and i start typing the name of a country in the select2 textbox the list is messed up.  I mean the css is not retrieved properly.

css looks like this :

```
.new-proj .select2-results {

 }
```

But the select2-results is hidden and its created outside of the controller at runtime and outside of the .new-proj class, is there anyway i can fix it, by restricting the runtime select2 created outside of controller div.

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="new-proj"> 
    .... Controller content here ...
    </div>
    <div class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none select2-drop-active"  
     style="top: 38.986111640930176px; left: 7.986111640930176px; width: 200px; display: none;">     
        <ul class="select2-results">
           <li class="select2-no-results">No matches found</li></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: select2 js appends result to body so to achieve this you need to alter the select2 jQuery plugin